# 5.1 DSS - Horror film genre Question

Tags: mixing, 5.1, surround-sound, sound-design

Hello to all. Im a 3rd year student investigating The use of DSS in question 5.1 in the horror film genre - with the intention of re-doing the audio for the end scene of "The Ring" in 5.1. Id like to ask a few questions your responses would be much appreciated

1.DSS having roughly double the headroom in perceived loudness (about 10db) than compared to Dolby SR - how can this be taken advantage of creatively, is it best to make everything louder?

2.For Music, Sound FX Dialogue tracks what are the db levels in general for these tracks.

3.A lot of FX/Dialogue will used will be ghostly heavy-breathing, breathing rises to create the presence of a supernatural being. Where is it best use these effects in the 5.1 spectrum. Without distracting the audience from the horror of the scene?

Thank you very much
Tommy Helling

Answer (score 1):

1. It is best to use the extra head room for dynamics rather than continuous loudness, especially in a horror film, dynamics is your most powerful tool.
2. Set up a monitor level to a standard 85 dB, ten use your ears. While working on loud scenes for an extended period you can reduce the SPL to say 80, but switch back to 85 from time to time to check your work. Then "If it sounds good, it IS good!"
3. Off screen can be distracting if unmotivated by action. For example, sounds that seem to come from off screen are distracting when the source is on screen. If you've established that the dialog comes out of the center speaker, you need to respect that with your effects, too. It's significant when breathing leaves the center, so use that consciously to build dread. Breathing coming from all around the 5.1 space implies that we are seeing the POV of the breather.

Have fun!